# How to handle outgoing and incoming activity using dependency service in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Now I found one xamarin forms github project but there is no incoming call activityand outgoing call as well. I use to develop this link(https://github.com/Onotseike/SinchCallDemo), once check this link after let me know what i went wrong, give me suggestion to resolve this issue

Comment: Your question is not quite clear please be clear about what you are trying to achieve here!!

Comment: We try implement voip voice call using xamarin forms using sinch(third party), so far i have created interface and implement each platform. what is my question, when i click on call button, it is not working. what i went wrong, I use to develop this link(https://github.com/Onotseike/SinchCallDemo)

Comment: Check if you followed the steps correctly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: i know how to use dependency service, my problem i need to call using internet, i have been looking couple of days but i could not find solution, i don't know how to implement voip call in my xamarin forms application, i tried sinch, cometchat, portsip, etc, none of these help for me